# Mongo lookup rounding a date

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm a beginner using `Mongo`. I have to embed one or more documents into another document, where the key used for the lookup is a `ISODate` that should be rounded down to the second. How can I achieve this result?

And what if I should perform the lookup on more than one keys, let's say `DtEvent` and `WorkstationId`?

This is a sample dataset:

`temperature` collection:

```
{
    "WorkstationId" : 1,
    "DtEvent" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:10.723Z"),
    "ParameterName" : "temperature",
    "ParameterValue" : 232.1
}
{
    "WorkstationId" : 1,
    "DtEvent" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:56.622Z"),
    "ParameterName" : "temperature",
    "ParameterValue" : 231.9
}
```

`pressure` collection:

```
{
    "WorkstationId" : 1,
    "DtEvent" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:10.725Z"),
    "ParameterName" : "pressure",
    "ParameterValue" : 3276.69
}
{
    "WorkstationId" : 1,
    "DtEvent" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:56.641Z"),
    "ParameterName" : "pressure",
    "ParameterValue" : 3276.69
}
{
    "WorkstationId" : 1,
    "DtEvent" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:01:42.622Z"),
    "ParameterName" : "pressure",
    "ParameterValue" : 3276.69
}
```

I've tried to do the following:

```
db.pressure.aggregate([{    
    $lookup: {
        from: "temperature",
        localField: "DtEvent",
        foreignField: "DtEvent",
        as: "temperature"        
    }
}])
```

But, as expected, the document is not embedded since the key is not exactly matching:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e738e151cc1692a9ace9b8c"),
    "WorkstationId" : 1,
    "DtEvent" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:10.725Z"),
    "ParameterName" : "pressure",
    "ParameterValue" : 3276.69,
    "temperature" : []
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e738e151cc1692a9ace9b8f"),
    "WorkstationId" : 1,
    "DtEvent" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:56.641Z"),
    "ParameterName" : "pressure",
    "ParameterValue" : 3276.69,
    "temperature" : []
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e738e151cc1692a9ace9b92"),
    "WorkstationId" : 1,
    "DtEvent" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:01:42.622Z"),
    "ParameterName" : "pressure",
    "ParameterValue" : 3276.69,
    "temperature" : []
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic `$lookup` expects **exact matching**. Since your `Dates` are not exact values, you need run [uncorrelated sub-query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup)

```
db.pressure.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "temperature",
      let: {
        dt_event: {
          $dateToString: {
            date: "$DtEvent",
            format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
          }
        }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$dt_event",
                {
                  $dateToString: {
                    date: "$DtEvent",
                    format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "temperature"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2tAZiABb_Vd)

**Note:** MongoDB won't use indexes, so it will have poor performance for large collection

Comment: Thank you @Valijon, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Andrea You are welcome. Also, you may normalize your dates in MongoDB (remove milisecs) and perform classic `$lookup` which will have high performance.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't edit the already existent data, it is from a production environment that I cannot modify. I was thinking about creating a view with your suggestion, I don't know if mongo supports materialization, may be a good compromise.

Comment: @Andrea Sure. MongoDB suport materialized view (well, it create a new collection instead) where you save your data normalized and perform aggregation